# Flutter : Prompt user to enter address details on opening the app for first time

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner and require help from Flutter experts here. I am building an app where users can browse/buy products sold within the apartment community. This requires user to enter address details(society name, apartment name) as soon as they open the app. I do not want to prompt them for signup yet. Is there a way where I can create a temporary profile in background and then prompt user to enter address details which can be stored in the user profile or is there any better way of achieving this.

Appreciate much for all your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the user address data in [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) (key-value pair), and retrieve the address when the user opens the app

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the user address at the time of opening the app, just call it in the initState() of your home screen. If the address is null you can show the prompt.